# Connect to postgresql database without a password

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have no problem connecting to a PostgreSQL database locally on a server without a password on the commandline i.e., `$ psql -d dname` takes me straight into the database `dname` with no errors and no prompts for passwords etc. However, when I try to connect in Python (still locally on the server) then it says:

```
In [7]: import psycopg2

In [9]: conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=dname port=5432 user=uname")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=dname port=5432 user=uname")

File /opt/miniconda3/envs/general/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:122, in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    119     kwasync['async_'] = kwargs.pop('async_')
    121 dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 122 conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    123 if cursor_factory is not None:
    124     conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

There is no password so I can't add one. I have done a lot of searching and the only solution that I have come across is to use the string `postgresql://localhost:5432/` to connect. However, I can't find a way to connect to DBs using Psycopg2 using strings like these.

It seemed like it was easier to change to a Python library that uses connection strings like this so I then tried SQL Alchemy but got the same problem of not having a password.

```
In [10]: import sqlalchemy

In [11]: db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://localhost:5432/dname')

In [12]: conn = db.connect()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
... (LONG ERROR)
...
File /opt/miniconda3/envs/general/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:122, in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    119     kwasync['async_'] = kwargs.pop('async_')
    121 dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 122 conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    123 if cursor_factory is not None:
    124     conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory
 
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) fe_sendauth: no password supplied
 
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Following the suggested link gives me

> OperationalError
>
> Exception raised for errors that are related to the database’s operation and not >necessarily under the control of the programmer, e.g. an unexpected disconnect occurs, the >data source name is not found, a transaction could not be processed, a memory allocation >error occurred during processing, etc.
>
> This error is a DBAPI Error and originates from the database driver (DBAPI), not >SQLAlchemy itself.
>
> The OperationalError is the most common (but not the only) error class used by drivers in >the context of the database connection being dropped, or not being able to connect to the >database. For tips on how to deal with this, see the section Dealing with Disconnects.

Which I don't fully understand but makes me wonder if there is something strange going on under the hood which is resulting in a misleading error and maybe the password isn't the problem.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

OS: Ubunutu20
pg_hba.conf file: is empty

Comment: Which operating system user runs the Python program? What is in `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: @user56700 I don't think so. I have found the hba file but it is empty. However, the post you suggested said "and set the environment variables PGUSER, PGDATABASE, etc to ensure that the connection is right." which I do not understand. Do you know what the should be set to and what format the file should take?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It is Ubuntu20 and the pg_hba.conf file is empty., I will update the post also.

Comment: `pg_hba.conf` cannot be empty. If it were, you could not connect with `psql`. Perhaps you are looking at the wrong file.

Comment: Remove host=localhost from your connection string. Then you will connecting to the Unix socket, the same as when you do psql -d dname. Same for SQLAlchemy connection string.